# Best practice to avoid throwing exceptions on endpoints?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, endpoint

I am exposing HTTP endpoints—outputting JSON exclusively—using Bottle.

Errors currently throw: `{'error': %s, 'error_message': %s, 'status_code': #}`.

So in all my endpoint decoratored functions I have:

```py
try:
    someObj = <stuff>
except <MyCustomErrors> as e:
    response.status = e.response.pop('status_code', 500)
    return e.response

response.status = someObj.response.pop('status_code', 200)

return someObj.response
```

But I could just as easily avoid using exceptions alltogether, resulting in more concise + DRYer endpoint code with reduced overhead.

There are disadvantages however; other devs will need to read—or run—through the code at least once to understand the output format.

**Documentation will work here; however is this whole setup bad practice?**

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I wrote this poor substitute:

```
# Not a decorator because I can't work out how to give `@route(apply=)` func args
def error_else_response(init_with):
    try:
        result = init_with(**request.query)
    except <CustomError> as e:
        response.status = e.msg.pop('status_code')
        return e.msg

    response.status = result.response.pop('status_code')

    return result.response


@route('/augment')
def augment():
    return error_else_response(<CustomClass>)
```